# App is not changing the language when I switch to another language in the iPhone Settings

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, localization, programming-languages

I have a strange problem with my app "Apnea Trainer". This app has multiple languages, the default localization is English. Since I sent the last update to Apple (November 2012) I haven't touched the app, Xcode or my Mac OS. Yesterday I decided to start with a new update, but when I tried to run the app the first time this year on the simulator or iPhone it started with German language. I used localizable strings for all languages, but I'm unable to change the language with changing the language in the iOS settings (happens on iPhone and simulator).

What I tried:
- Restart everything
- Changing device' and simulator's language several times to German an back to English
- Removed Xcode and install it again
- Checked for Xcode updates (had the latest version)
- Updated the iPhone from iOS 6.0 to 6.0.1
- Checked the app I sent to Apple... works fine as it should

---

Edit:
After trying to change the region format... all files are red now, but I don't get any errors and the app is running, but still in German (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoZRi.jpg)

---

Edit Two:

I tried to run the app on another Mac. Same OS, same Xcode version, same problem. The first build was ok, when I started the app the second time it was running in German

What can I do???

---

Edit Three:

I even setup a new project, but when I copy the content of the storyboard, the problem is back.

Answer (score 4):

XCODE 6 completely ignores the settings of the iPhone.

In XCODE goto "edit scheme" (next to the "stop"-button).

Run/Options/Application language.

Here you change the setting.

Make sure you dont have anything set in

Run/Arguments/Arguments Passed On Launch

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing region?
Settings -> General -> International -> Region Format

Comment: Hi, just tried it but it's still in German and now are all files red but I don't get any erros.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/NoZRi.jpg